# Problema con instalación Spark en Windows Server 2012

Tags: java, python, windows

Hola a todos estoy instalando spark en Windows server siguiendo la siguiente guía https://bigdata-madesimple.com/guide-to-install-spark-and-use-pyspark-from-jupyter-in-windows/ , el problema de ello es que al querer correr spark con el siguiente comando `bin\pyspark` me genera la siguiente excepción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado cambiar las versiones de java y spark pero no me ha resultado nada.

La versión de java que tengo en estos momentos es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su atención y quedo atento a cualquier comentario.

Comment: Ya instalaste Hadoop?

Comment: Si, pero me sigue apareciendo lo mismo.